# Load C signed long in Java

Tags: java

I have a 4-byte `signed long` variable in C/C++ which is saved in a file using memcpy.

File content: "31E04CFB".

I need to load this value in Java, but Java's `int` (4 bytes) and C++'s `long` have different memory structures. Is there any library which will help me with this, or I have to code it myself?

Comment: I think that's just a [hexidecimal number](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) with the normal '0x' appended to the start.

Comment: Is 836783355 the right number?

Comment: [long](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) isn't always 4 bytes in C++. But assuming it is, you just need a 4 byte equivalent in Java, which appears to be [int](https://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/134-modern-java/5423-java-data-types-numeric-data.html).

Comment: @lucasvw, nope, it is not. One bit for example represents sign of the value.

Comment: @wair92 Which bit, specifically? Is this value represented in big endian or little endian?

Comment: @BoristheSpider OP specified `signed long`

Comment: Read it into a `byte[]` and then convert from there.

Comment: How do you know what c++'s long memory structure is?

Comment: what is different memory structures? the hexadecimal representation should be the same (I doubt this is [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - would be a very *irregular* representation) - try `Integer.decode(String)`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger If the number is stored using `memcpy`, then it's a binary file. `Integer.decode(String)` won't work.

Comment: @JacobG.little endian. Highest bit.

Comment: @Janez but does `File content: "0x31E04CFB` look like binary???

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, my mistake, sorry, I edited it,

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger *"... which is saved in a file using memcpy."* What can I say - it's confusing at best.

Comment: maybe it would have been much clearer if you had a better (simpler) number and the file content - hard to guess what is the Endianness of that file and anyway - kind of dangerous to use such a format at all

Comment: @wair92 Because you've specified little endian, you can reverse the bytes with `Integer.reverseBytes(0x31E04CFB)`, which returns `-78847951`. Is that the value you're expecting?

Comment: @Janez sorry, I've stopped using C/C++ more than 20 years ago... kind of hard to remember how to store a number in a file using `memcpy`

Comment: @JacobG.yes, that's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks !!!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Well the OP probably meant to say that he first copied the number(s) to some sort of "write buffer" using `memcpy` and then wrote the buffer to a file as binary data. Your guess is as good as mine though!:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you the one writing the file? Do you understand about big-endian versus little-endian?

If you want a portable file, writing raw bytes isn't how you do it. Do you have the choice of a different file format?

If so, consider it. Store it as a string instead of raw bytes.

If not, then you need to understand the big-endian /little-endian status on the hardware you're using, and it will NOT be portable.